# Kendo UI Grid with local data is not getting create/update/delete permanently:

Tags: kendo-grid

I am using Kendo Grid with local data. I have some records in seperate js file and included in jsp.

```
 var studentsNextID = students.length + 1;

        function getIndexById(id) {
            var idx,
                l = students.length;

            for (var j=0; j < l; j++) {
                if (students[j].StudentID == id) {
                    return j;
                }
            }
            return null;
        }

        $(document).ready(function() {
        var dataSource= new kendo.data.DataSource({
            transport:{
                read:function(e){
                    e.success(students);
                },
                update: function(e){
                    students[getIndexById(e.data.StudentID)]=e.data;
                    e.success();
                },
                destroy: function(e){
                    studetns.splice(getIndexById(e.data.StudentID),1)
                    e.success();
                },
                create: function(e){
                    e.data.StudentID=studentsNextID++;
                    students.push(e.data);
                    e.success(e.data);
                }
            }
```

I am able to create/update/delete it well, but the changes are not affecting permanently. If i refreshing or run my program again, it reads previous data.

1. Is it possible to make CRUD functions permanently in local data?
2. Can we create our own Remote data ?

I am new to these concepts, if i made any mistake, kindly apologize. Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you provide a jsFiddle for your query?

Comment: When you refresh the page, the separate js file that contains the records will also be reloaded, which will reset students back to whatever is contained in the js file.  Updating the in-memory students array will not permanently change the hard-coded students definition in the separate js file.